# intercept a call when a button is clicked

Tags: cypress

I have the following steps

1. Click button
2. when the button is clicked, a save request is being sent
3. the website navigate to other page

Now I need to intercept the request sent to the backend to get information not displayed on the other page (date of appointment including timestamp and zone for instance)

I have the following code

```
    let date = ''
    cy.intercept('POST', '**/appointments/v1', (req) => {
        // make an assertion on the payload contents
        expect(req.body).not.to.be.null
        console.log(req.body['date'])
        date = req.body['date']
    }).as('appointment')
    cy.get('[data-cy="appointment-confirm"]').should('exist').find('button')
        .click({force: true})
    cy.wait('@appointment')
```

the request is being intercepted on the abovementioned code, but the navigation to the next page is will not take place, as I I have not clicked the button at all. The data of the request are also not saved to the backend.

I looks like the intercepted request is being stopped

I have also used

```
let date = ''
cy.intercept('POST', '**/appointments/v1', (req) => {
    // make an assertion on the payload contents
    expect(req.body).not.to.be.null
    console.log(req.body['date'])
    date = req.body['date']
}).as('appointment')
cy.get('[data-cy="appointment-confirm"]').should('exist').find('ion-button')
    .click({force: true}).then(()=>{
    cy.wait('@appointment')
})
```

I have also treid

```
    cy.intercept('POST', '**/appointments/v1', (request) => {
        expect(request.body).not.to.be.null
        console.log(request.body['date'])
        date = request.body['date']
        request.continue()
    }).as('appointment')
```

but have the same issue
I have figured out, that the intercepted request is now returning 400 Bad request

[image]

Comment: hi, so you only want to save the request body right?

Answer (score 5):

IMO, actually your code almost correct and I suggest you to try something like this

```
cy.intercept({ method: 'POST', url: '**/roles' }).as('responseRole')

// after intercept you can click the button
cy.get('button').click()

// and wait for cypress to get the result as alias
cy.wait('@responseRole').then(({ request, response }) => {
  console.log(request.body)
  console.log(response.body)
})
```

Comment: This did not help either, the request returns the same error. Bad request

Comment: does the feature run normally if manual test? do you fill form data in UI before click the button? if you just want to get the request data don't stub your endpoint , if you do it can caused 400 bad request.

Comment: I dont want to stub the data but intercept them :) that is what i am trying to do actually. According to cypress documentation cy.intercept is used to intercept calls

Comment: IMO, if your service return 400 bad request, its not from cypresss side

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple scenarios and I almost had the same issue. I changed the sequence and it worked. Such that:

1. Click Button
2. Intercept
3. Wait

This happens because `requestTimeout` of `cy.wait()` needs the API to fire before intercept.
For reference see here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Timeouts

Your code should look like this:

```
let date = '';
cy.get('[data-cy="appointment-confirm"]').should('exist').find('button')
    .click({force: true});
cy.intercept('POST', '**/appointments/v1', (req) => {
    // make an assertion on the payload contents
    expect(req.body).not.to.be.null
    console.log(req.body['date'])
    date = req.body['date']
}).as('appointment');
cy.wait('@appointment');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the **wrong order**. If it's passing, it's just luck or some other intercept having an effect on this code.